# Firebase / React - Prevent Host Header attack

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working to remedy some security vulnerabilities from a penetration test. The vulnerability in question is a "Web Server Vulnerable to HTTP Host Header Attack" with a recommendation of "...the Host request header is user specified and shouldn't be trusted. Ensure that strict white listing is used to validate the Host header."

I am currently using React.js as my frontend frame work and Firebase for Functions (Node.js), Hosting, Authentication, Storage and Analytics. I am not understanding from my general internet search where or even what I should be changing to remedy this vulnerability? I am gathering that I may be using code in my server calls that is using the raw "HOST" variable, but I don't see anywhere in my code this is accessed explicitly. I do have an `functions.https.onCall()` function, which is maybe using the HOST internally. Obviously have many `onCreate()`, `onUpdate()`, etc calls. Maybe it is another function or library I am using behind the scenes?

What is the solution to prevent host header attacks on Firebase?

**Firebase Functions package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^4.10.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.7",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "order-id": "^2.1.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Hosting, the report it likely referring to the fact that the `Host` header is used to route requests to the appropriate site. This is working as intended -- since Firebase Hosting is a multi-tenant service, the `Host` header provides necessary information to disambiguate between sites.

No action should be necessary on your part - Firebase already carefully validates the header against known sites.